# Constructing a ternary (n,M,d) code

Tags: coding-theory

We have ternary (3,9,2) code called $C$. I know that such a code does exist. What I have trouble with is writing down all the code-words of $C$.

I know that the first two digits in each code-word can be represented by $(F_{3})^{2}$. These have distance = 1.

I now need to show that by adding an additional digit to the code-words of length 2 above, I can get a set of code-words of length 3, with $d(C)\geq2$.

What I am asking is, how does one choose that last digit to satisfy  $d(C) \geq2$ for each code-word?

I end up doing it through trial and error, but that is time consuming and I'm sure there is a better and more efficient way to write these code-words down? For instance, how would a programmer go about generating this code above?

Thanks

Comment: Try choosing the third symbol $c_3$ to be the _additive inverse_ of the sum of the first two, that is, $c_3 = -(c+1 + c_2)$ and report back to us if it works.

Comment: I'm assuming you meant $c_{3} = -(c_{1}+c_{2})$? If so, it does seem to work. Is there a reason for why the additive inverse  $c_{3}$ satisfies all the code-words such that $d(C) \geq 2$?

Comment: Yes, that should have been $c_1$, not $c+1$$. Read a little further along where they might mention the words "parity check".

Comment: The text I am reading goes right into parity check matrices. It says that if $v$ is not a codeword of $C$, then $vG^{t}=\textbf{0}$, where G is the generator matrix of C. This relates to linear codes however. In the problem given, are we dealing with a linear code?

I still can't see why the equation $c_{3}=−(c_{1}+c_{2})$ must be satisfied.

Comment: "It says that if $v$ is not a codeword of $C$, then $vG^t=0$, where $G$ is the generator matrix of $C$." This is so dreadfully incorrect that I cannot believe that it is what your text says. Can you check if you have correctly transcribed what your book says, and if this is so, please reveal to us the title and the author of the book.

Comment: That was a mistake on my part. It was an incorrect summary of what the lemma was stating.